# Delete/Remove main file and attachment from Nuxeo

Tags: nuxeo

Through my own custom listener I would like to delete main files and attachment from the nuxeo document.
Deleting the document seems to be easy as you can use the below code.

> doc.getCoreSession().removeDocument(doc.getRef());
>   doc.getCoreSession().save();

But how I can delete the file and attachment through my java code. Please provide me a snippet of code.

Comment: Please, don't cross-post over sites: https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/94f7637ee05644a8a31e892bb6a9218b/Delete-attachment-thorough-Java

Comment: Thanks for the information. This would be a great help also if anyone can post the answer in any forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be..

```
DocumentHelper.removeProperty(documentModel, path);
```

path = file:content for main file. For attachment "files/content[array index]"